# grails 1.3.1 Error executing script GenerateViews:

Tags: google-app-engine, grails, groovy

Here is the lay of the land. I have an app that I have created. I uninstalled hibernate, installed app-engine plugin and am using jdo.

I am able to create a domain-class but the when I run generate-all I run into the following error.

Oh and I did try just generating the controller for the domain class and that seemed to work fine but then after that I try just generate-views on the same domain class and I also get the following error.

> Error executing script GenerateViews: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:391)
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
>       at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>       at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>       at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>       at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>       at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>       at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>       at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
>       at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at SimpleTemplateScript1.run(SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy:43)
>       at _GrailsGenerate_groovy.generateForDomainClass(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:85)
>       at _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:50)
>       at GenerateViews$_run_closure1.doCall(GenerateViews.groovy:33)
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
>       ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/mapping/Value
>       ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.mapping.Value
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>       ... 15 more
>   --- Nested Exception ---
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at SimpleTemplateScript1.run(SimpleTemplateScript1.groovy:43)
>       at _GrailsGenerate_groovy.generateForDomainClass(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:85)
>       at _GrailsGenerate_groovy$_run_closure1.doCall(_GrailsGenerate_groovy:50)
>       at GenerateViews$_run_closure1.doCall(GenerateViews.groovy:33)
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure5.doCall(Gant.groovy:381)
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy:415)
>       at gant.Gant$_dispatch_closure7.doCall(Gant.groovy)
>       at gant.Gant.withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy:427)
>       at gant.Gant.this$2$withBuildListeners(Gant.groovy)
>       at gant.Gant$this$2$withBuildListeners.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
>       at gant.Gant.dispatch(Gant.groovy:415)
>       at gant.Gant.this$2$dispatch(Gant.groovy)
>       at gant.Gant.invokeMethod(Gant.groovy)
>       at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:590)
>       at gant.Gant.executeTargets(Gant.groovy:589)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/mapping/Value
>       ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.mapping.Value
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.findClass(RootLoader.java:156)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>       at org.codehaus.groovy.tools.RootLoader.loadClass(RootLoader.java:128)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
>       ... 15 more

Answer (score 2):

The `GenerateViews.groovy` script appears to have a dependency on the hibernate plugin. A workaround is to re-install the hibernate plugin, then prevent it from being used at runtime by adding the following to `Config.groovy`

```
plugin {
    excludes = ["hibernate"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the GenerateViews script has a dependency on some classes from the hibernate plugin (org.hibernate.mapping.Value).  I'd try putting the hibernate plugin back in place to run these scripts.

Can the two persistence plugins coexist?